# How to create mock a web cam, using an Android phone on Ubuntu-14.04

Tags: android, python, opencv, ubuntu, video-streaming

I am trying to develop an application with Python using opencv. Since I don't own a webcam, I want a way I can use my android phone's camera as a webcam for my PC. I know there are applications like ip webcam and many more. But none of them seem to provide a device driver for Ubuntu-14.04. (I have tried Wo webcam in Windows and have failed to access it as a webcam from my program). Please suggest what I can do to use my phone as a webcam for the PC.

PS: alternatively, if accessing the video stream from any existing ip cam applications through your code, please explain the solution.

Comment: I would rather use some of the existing applications' video stream for my own app. This seems to give the stream to the browser (http://ip-webcam.appspot.com/). But I wasn't able to access it with my code. (In this android app, if you go to this link http://ip-adress:port/video in the browser, you get a video stream.)

Comment: Do you *need* a live video stream to write your application? Why not just record a 30 second (or whatever length) video and use `cv::VideoReader` to display the video and write your application?